# Non-numerical value for derivative at boundary using ParametricNDSolve to find eigenvalues using a simple shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I have this code:

```
V[x_] = If[x <= -1, ∞, 1]*If[-1 < x < -a, 0, 1]*If[-a <= x <= a, V1, 1]*If[a < x < 1, 0, 1]*If[1 <= x, ∞, 1] /. {a -> 1/4}
sg = -psi''[x]/2 + V[x]*psi[x] == EE *psi[x] ;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sg, psi[-1]==0, psi'[-1]==1},psi, {x, -1, 1}, {EE, V1}]
Evaluate[psi[5, 30][1] /. sol]
Plot[Evaluate[psi[5, 30][x] /. sol], {x, -1, 1}]
```

I can't not explain the error:

> `ParametricNDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == -1.. >>`

and

> `Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. \[Infinity] encountered. >>`

Comment: I don't think you can use `Infinity` in your potential function `V`. You should instead specify the boundary conditions at `x = -1` and `x == 1` that the function should be zero.

Comment: I tried to change V and set the boundary conditions:
    sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sg, psi[-1] == 0, psi[1] == 0, 
   psi'[-1] == 1}, psi, {x, -1, 1}, {EE, V1}]
But this can't be solved:
"NDSolve is not currently able to solve boundary value problems with \
discrete variables. "

Comment: Thank you for the accept! Usually it's a good idea to wait a day or so before accepting an answer for the purposes of attracting other answers (an accepted answer gets fewer looks). When you have enough reputation, please upvote the answers that you get that you like! Welcome to mathematica.SE. (I changed the title a bit; if you really feel like it, feel free to change it back, but it's a good idea for the titles to be as specific as possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original Post

The problem is that you have introduced a discontinuity in the derivative of your function by specifying that the potential energy for `x <= -1` is infinite. If you remove the factors of `If[x <= -1, ∞, 1]` and `If[x >= 1, ∞, 1]`, your code runs fine, because it now has no problem applying the boundary conditions at `x == -1`.

Here is your code, a little cleaned up. You can use one or the other of the definitions of `v` below:

```
v[x_, a_?Positive] := Piecewise[{{v1, -a <= x <= a}}]
v[x_, a_?Positive] := v1 UnitBox[x/(2 a)]
Plot[v[x, 1/4] /. v1 -> 10, {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> False]
```

[image]

Then, the Schrodinger equation is given by

```
sg[a_?Positive] := -psi''[x]/2 + v[x, a]*psi[x] == EE*psi[x];
```

and we solve this via

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sg[1/4], psi[-1] == 0, psi'[-1] == 1}, psi, {x, -1, 1}, {EE, v1}];
```

Finally, we use `FindRoot` to see where the function goes to zero one left boundary and plot. For instance,

```
pot = 10;
energy = FindRoot[Evaluate[psi[e, pot][1] == 0 /. sol], {e, 5}]
(* { e -> 5.64844} *)
```

and

```
Plot[Evaluate[psi[e /. energy, pot][x] /. sol], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

### Update

Let's see how well `ParametricNDSolve` does with this problem. The energy eigenvalues for the `v1 -> 1` potential (i.e. just an infinite square well of width 2 units) should be

```
((π^2)/8)*Range[9]^2
```

[image]

My favorite way of quickly extracting numerical roots is as follows. Plot the function whose roots give us the energies with the roots found, i.e.

```
p1 = Plot[psi[e, 0][1] /. sol
  , {e, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}
  , MeshFunctions -> Function[#2], Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.015], Red}]
```

[image]

Extract the zeroes and refine them with `FindRoot` (this second step isn't *entirely* necessary, but it gets us better precision) via

```
rawEnergies = Sort@Cases[Normal@p1, Point[{a_, _}] :> a, Infinity]
refinedEnergies = e /. FindRoot[Evaluate[psi[e, 0][1] == 0 /. sol], {e, #}] & /@ rawEnergies
```

[image]

Finally, how close are they to the real values? Multiply by `8/π^2`:

```
8/π^2 # & /@ refinedEnergies
(* {1., 4., 9., 16., 25., 36., 49., 64., 81.} *)
```

Excellent!

Finally:

```
Plot[Evaluate[psi[#, 0][x] & /@ refinedEnergies /. sol], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Those look like very nice sinusoidal functions!

**Energies as a function of the height of the bump**

Let's automate the procedure!

```
energies[v1_, maxE_] := Module[{p1, rawEnergies, refinedEnergies}
  , p1 = Plot[psi[e, v1][1] /. sol, {e, 0, maxE}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}, MeshFunctions -> Function[#2], Mesh -> {{0}}]
  ; rawEnergies = Sort@Cases[Normal@p1, Point[{a_, _}] :> a, Infinity]
  ; refinedEnergies = {v1, e /. FindRoot[Evaluate[psi[e, v1][1] == 0 /. sol], {e, #}]} & /@rawEnergies
 ]
```

This is somewhat inefficient, but it works well enough. We do this root-finding for a number `v1`s via

```
egys = Table[energies[v1, 100], {v1, 0, 30, 0.5}];
```

This spits out some errors because sometimes `FindRoot` has some problems, but here it doesn't matter. Finally, we plot this using

```
Show[
  ListLinePlot[Flatten[egys, {2}]
   , PlotRange -> {0, 40}
   , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"V", Style["E", Italic]}
   , BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> 15}
  ]
  , Plot[Evaluate[\[Pi]^2/8 Range[9]^2], {x, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
 ]
```

resulting in

[image]

The dashed curves are the particle-in-a-box energies.  (By the way, the list of energies that we make might be ragged, because the energies get pushed up by the potential bump. For this reason, we have to transpose a ragged array, and we do this using the magic that is the second argument to `Flatten`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works just fine.

Comment: But wait, there's more!